# Вывести данные полученные посредством API, в браузер, и записать в БД

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Пример массива:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => zxcv
        [next_page_id] => abcd
        [suggestions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => data
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => data2
                    )

            )

    )
```

Предположим что на первой странице выводится 100 записей, а следующие можно получить передав аргумент **next_page_id**, мне нужно показать пользователю количество записей из первой страницы, но при этом записать в БД все данные со всех страниц, получается нужно делать много запросов, и это занимает очень много времени... Есть ли возможность сделать вывод в браузер, при этом параллельно записывать в БД?

Я пока-что вижу только один вариант, это писать id текущего запроса в тег, или переменную js, затем делать ajax запрос... Возможно есть решение получше? Заранее спасибо. Основная задача, при первом запросе берем из API, выводим пользователю и пишем в БД, при последующих запросах если запись есть в БД, выводим если нет обращаемся к API.

Comment: можно вывести первую страницу, записать данные в бд, а потом уже через Ajax в цикле запрашивать по одной следующей странице и записывать данные в фоне, не меняя страницу.

Comment: Так я это вариант описал... Может есть другое решение, так сказать не зависящее от клиента.

Comment: например так, загружаем первую страницу и яксом создаем крон задачу, которая уже по крону загружает все остальное

Comment: Вы можете вызвать API на сервере и записанный в БД результат вернуть пользователю

Comment: @Alexus, Могу, но это займёт, секунд 5-6...

Comment: @VadimPedchenko вы отдаете клиенту первую страницу а сами в это время грузите другие

Comment: @Alexus, Как? Если скрипт не завершится пока не загрузит всё... Соответственно вывода в браузер не будет...

Comment: @VadimPedchenko Схема такая: 1) отдаете пользователю первую страницу  2) запускаете отдельный процесс в котором вы складываете все в БД.

Comment: @Alexus, Как запустить отдельный процесс? PCNTL?  Никогда с ним не работал... Можно пример? Или есть другой способ? И PCNTL работает только из под cli, или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема следующая:

1. идет запрос в БД и если эта информация есть в БД возвращаете ее
   пользователю
2. если ее нет в БД считываете первую страницу из АПИ, записываете ее в
   БД и отдаете пользователю
3. запускаете отдельный поток для последующих страниц

Функция(взята из открытых источников) которая "запускает" отдельный поток.
Здесь $url это url вашего скрипта работающего в фоне.
Функция не ждет завершения скрипта

```
function exec_script($url, $params = array())
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if( isset($params['PHPSESSID']) ) unset($params['PHPSESSID']);
    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80);
    if ($fp == FALSE )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $data = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    fwrite($fp, "POST " . (!empty($parts['path']) ? $parts['path'] : '/') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0\r\n".
                                "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
                                "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n".
                                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);

    return true;
}
```

Нужно будет решить что делать если пользователь сразу запросил 9 страницу к примеру...

Comment: 1, 2, это понятно... Но откуда возьмётся второй поток? Скрипт всё равно будет ждать выполнения fsock... Или я чего то не понял?

Comment: @VadimPedchenko функция заставит Web сервер запустить ваш скрипт без ожидания ответа и закроет соединение. Можете проверить: сделайте sleep(10) в проверяемом потоке и увидите результат .

Comment: @VadimPedchenko e у меня эта функция отлично работает.

Comment: Спасибо, вечером проверю.